# CSS3 issue with Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am new to CSS3 and trying to learn. I make simple page with css but it render properly in chrome but in firefox it render bad. My code is as below. Kindly help me on it.

It looks like there is problem in face class in css
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css3flip.css" />
  </head>
  <body>


<section id="game">
  <div id="cards">
    <div id="card">
      <div class="face front"></div>
      <div class="face back cardAK"></div>
    </div> <!-- .card -->
    <div id="card">
      <div class="face front"></div>
      <div class="face back cardAQ"></div>
    </div> <!-- .card -->
  </div> <!-- #cards -->
</section> <!-- #game -->

<footer>
  <p>This is an example of flipping cards with CSS3.</p>
  <p>Click on the card to flip.</p>
</footer>

<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>

  $(function(){
    $("#cards").children().each(function(index){
      // listen the click event of each card DIV element.
      $(this).click(function(){
        // add the class "card-flipped"
        // the browser animate the styles between current state and card-flipped state.
        $(this).toggleClass("card-flipped");
      });
    });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#game {
background: #9c9;
padding: 5px;
}

#card {
-webkit-perspective: 600;
width: 80px;
height: 120px;
margin: 8px;
}

.face {
border-radius: 10px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
-webkit-transition: all .3s;    
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
} 

.front {
background: #966;
z-index: 10;
}

.back {
background: #eaa;
-webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,-180deg);
z-index: 8;
}

.card-flipped .front {
-webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,180deg);
z-index: 8;
}

.card-flipped .back {
-webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,0deg);
z-index: 10;
}

.cardAK {
background: url(../images/AK.png) no-repeat;
}

.cardAQ {
background: url(../images/AQ.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Images

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**http://jsfiddle.net/SANBA/1/**

you define css for fire fox too like u did for chrome `-webkit-` is for chrome and for firefox it is `-moz-`

add similar line for firefox too
for example

```
-webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,-180deg);for chrome
-moz-transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,-180deg); for fire fox
```

i have updated your css please use this

```
 #game {
    background: #9c9;
    padding: 5px;
}
#card {

      width: 80px;
    height: 120px;
position:relative; 
    margin: 8px;
}
.face {
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-transition: all .3s;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: all .3s;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.front {
    background: #966;
    z-index: 10;
}
.back {
    background: #eaa;
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -180deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -180deg);
    z-index: 8;
}
.card-flipped .front {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg);
    z-index: 8;
}
.card-flipped .back {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 0deg);
    z-index: 10;
}
.cardAK {
    background: url(../images/AK.png) no-repeat;
}
.cardAQ {
    background: url(../images/AQ.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I use your code but still it is same no change.

Comment: i have created a fiddle please check it